# basepath for action-mappings in Struts

Tags: java, struts

If I have a list of action tags inside an action-mappings, is it possible to define a basepath ?

Now I have something like:

```
 <action-mappings>
    <action path="/basepath/path1" forward="/jsp/pathl.jsp" />
    <action path="/basepath/path2" forward="/jsp/path2.jsp" />
 </action-mappings>
```

and I would like to do something like:

```
 <action-mappings basepath="/basepath">
    <action path="/path1" forward="/jsp/pathl.jsp" />
    <action path="/path2" forward="/jsp/path2.jsp" />
 </action-mappings>
```

Comment: Because if for some reason the basepath changes, I have to change it for every action.

Comment: Describe how do you change the `basepath` in the application or somwere.

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't think I follow. For basepath I mean a random subpath of the context root. Like in this case I'll have to change the string basepath in the path attribute of the tag action.

Comment: What's the problem of changing the string in the tag of the action?

Comment: it's just a repetition of a common string in every path. To me looks like really error prone.